# Can a wizard copy a spell without first identifying it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wizard

Let's say a Wizard finds a trove of spell scrolls. Rather than spending an hour per scroll identifying and then additional time and money copying it into their spellbook, can they simply copy the spell into their spellbook?

And, if so, would the act of copying identify it?

Comment: Related: [Can a Wizard identify the spells in another spellbook without copying them into their own?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120878) (basically the opposite case)

Comment: Related on [How do you identify what spell is on a spell scroll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68705/how-do-you-identify-what-spell-is-on-a-spell-scroll)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No, because identification is automatic

The [rules](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spell%20Scroll) say:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll …

Unless you want to play that scrolls are multiple pages of long, boring, irrelevant text (you know, like most fantasy novels), reading one takes seconds to minutes.

Comment: RAW: _Casting_ is automatic, if you specifically spend an action reading the scroll.  The full quote is "If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material Components."  Otherwise, you would either need to cast Identify on it, or handle it for one hour like any other magical item.  RAI? DM's discretion.

Comment: @Ghedipunk normal English usage of the conjunction “and”  includes “either” - only in Boolean logic does it mean “both”

Comment: @DaleM Not normally. It's only the case because of the word "can" creating a conditional. And, even then, this is colloquial usage, and most texts that are trying to be exact would use "or" or add "or both" to make it unambiguous.